# How to serialize fields on RealmObjects to different name?

Tags: android, json, realm

I am currently saving the JSON that I get back straight to my realm db via

`RealmObjectSubclass object = realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(RealmObjectSubclass.class, json);`

When you do this, similar to libraries like Gson, Realm will map the JSON keys to the field name of the class that you are saving.

However, unlike Gson, I don't see anyway in the Realm API to map a JSON key to a field unless they have the same name. This is usually solved in other JSON parsing libraries with annotations on the field like `@SerializableName("actualKeyNameInTheJson")`.

How can I go about achieving this in Realm?

Comment: You can't at the moment  https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/682#issuecomment-236517503

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for the quick response @EpicPandaForce. Is there an open feature request for this or should I make my own?

Comment: Well, you can make an issue if you want. I don't think it has one on its own.

Comment: Ok, I have opened on here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3622. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is an issue opened https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/682#issuecomment-252860499 :P

Comment: @beeender did see it, but it's by default scoped for other things. I'd say that comment is a duplicate of this new issue.